# How to select top 2 values for each id

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with values

```
id  sales     date
1   5   "2015-01-04"
1   3   "2015-01-03"
1   1   "2015-01-01"
1   1   "2015-01-01"
2   7   "2015-01-05"
2   6   "2015-01-04"
2   4   "2015-01-03"
3   11  "2015-01-08"
3   10  "2015-01-07"
3   9   "2015-01-06"
3   8   "2015-01-05"
```

I want to select top two values of each id as shown in desired output.

Desired output:

```
id   sales     date
 1    5        "2015-01-04"
 1    3        "2015-01-03"
 2    7        "2015-01-05"
 2    6        "2015-01-04"
 3    11       "2015-01-08"
 3    10       "2015-01-07"
```

My attempt:

can someone help me with this. Thank you in advance!

```
select transactions.salesperson_id, transactions.id, transactions.date
from transactions
ORDER BY transactions.salesperson_id ASC, transactions.date DESC;
```

Comment: "top two" based on what? The `sales` value? The `date`?

Comment: Top two based on date

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using window functions:

```
select id, sales, "date"
from (
  select id, sales, "date", 
         dense_rank() over (partition by id order by "date" desc) as rnk
  from transactions
) t
where rnk <= 2;
```

If there are multiple rows on the same date this might return more than two rows for the same ID. If you don't want that, use `row_number()` instead of `dense_rank()`

Comment: I am getting an error "subquery must have an alias name"

Comment: @DevanshuKhokhani: sorry, fixed

Answer (score 0):

`row_number()` will get what you want.

```
select * from 
    (select row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as rn, sales, date from transactions) t1
where t1.rn <= 2
```